# tKinter: Invalid File Error

Tags: file, dialog, tkinter, python-3.4

Whenever I attempt to save using this code:

```
def openfile(self):
    self.filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Extinction Save files", "*.exis"), ("All files", "*.*")))

def save(self):
    try:
        if not self.filename:
            self.filename = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".exis", filetypes=(("Extinction Save files", "*.exis"), ("All files", "*.*")))

        # if not '.exis' in self.filename:
        #     self.filename += ".exis"

        self.filename.close()
        with open(self.filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(self.compiledata)
    except Exception as error:
        print(str(error))

def saveas(self):
    try:
        self.filename = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".exis", filetypes=(("Extinction Save files", "*.exis"), ("All files", "*.*")))

        # if not '.exis' in self.filename:
        #     self.filename += ".exis"

        self.filename.close()
        with open(self.filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(self.compiledata)
    except Exception as error:
        print(str(error))

def compiledata(self):
    char = comboBox.currentText()
    health = lineEdit_2.text()
    level = lineEdit_3.text()
    XP = lineEdit_4.text()
    inv = []
    for index in range(self.listWidget.count()):
        inv.append(self.listWidget.item(index))

    return char + '\ninv[' + ', '.split(inv) + '\n]' + health + '\n' + level + '\n' + XP
```

I get the following error message:

`invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/Joan/Desktop/file.exis' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>`

I have seen one instance on this site where someone had a somewhat similar error message, but the solution did not help me. I just don't understand what I am supposed to do at this point.

Comment: Your title includes "pyqt5". What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @BryanOakley In the full code I used pyqt5, I added that to make sure it wasn't interfering with the code in any way. And if it was, well you knew what else I was using.

Comment: How are you using PyQt4 and Tkinter together? That seems like a recipe for disaster, since they both require their own event loop.

Comment: Well in my case it shouldn't, since for whatever reason I can't get PyQt5's dailog box to work so I just use tkinters dialog boxes. Not an actual event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `asksaveasfile()`, `self.filename` is not a filename, but an opened file. You then use `self.filename.close()`, so `self.filename` becomes a closed file, but `open(...)` expects a filename.

To get a the filename from the file you can use `self.filename.name`, so:

```
with open(self.filename.name, "w") as file:
```